# Oracle SQL Regexp

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-like

I have a `,` separated string values in two different columns and need to match a specific value between these two columns.
Example:

```
Column A: A123,B234,I555,K987
Column B: AAA1,A123,B234,I555,K987
```

I want to check the value `B234` from `Column A` (which is starting 6th position) and `B234` from `Column B` (which is starting 11th position), if they are matching or not. I have few hundred of such records and need to check if these values are matching or not.

Answer (score 2):

The way you put it, you'd compare "words" - the 2nd one in `column A` against the 3rd one in `column B` (sample data in lines #1 - 4; query you might be interested in begins at line #5):

```
SQL> with test (cola, colb) as
  2    (select 'A123,B234,I555,K987', 'AAA1,A123,B234,I555,K987' from dual union all
  3     select 'XYZ'                , 'DEF'                      from dual
  4    )
  5  select *
  6  from test
  7  where regexp_substr(cola, '\w+', 1, 2) = regexp_substr(colb, '\w+', 1, 3);

COLA                COLB
------------------- ------------------------
A123,B234,I555,K987 AAA1,A123,B234,I555,K987

SQL>
```

Comment: Did you notice the closure of this post? It seems a little off to me. The reference doesn't include Oracle's methods. I expect the only reason for the closure was the added regex tag.

Comment: No, I didn't, @Scratte. It is 2 years old and I think that SO doesn't notice us about closed discussions.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about "2 years old". The Question was asked at "2021-02-19 19:38:09", which was about a week ago. But I cannot vote to reopen, since I don't have the privileges.

Comment: Hahahha! LOL! "Feb 19" was "Feb 2019" to me :) Sorry, @Scratte. My bad. OK, I pushed the "Reopen" for you :)